# using onClick for double clicking on phone screen

Tags: reactjs

I am programming in Next.js and when I double click an image, I want it to fire a function called likePosts(). This works fine for desktop version, but on phone it doesn't work.

```
var timer;

function onClick(event) {
clearTimeout(timer);

if (event.detail === 2) {
    likePosts()
}

...

{/* img */}
<img onClick={onClick}
    src={img} 
    className="object-contain w-full" 
    alt="" 
/>
```

Does anyone have any idea for how I can fix this?